# Any way to identify/examine the thread that an external process is running in?

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime, exec

I am using Runtime.exec() to launch an external 16-bit DOS program (for legacy app compatibility reasons) within my Jave web application.  I have stream readers to capture the process's output, I have a timer to interrupt if it takes too long, and I use Process.waitFor() to wait until the process is done before I analyze the captured output.  It all works well, MOST of the time.

The problem is, the first time the app is requested for the day (we're not live yet), it times out.  I would really like to do some kind of monitoring  to tell what the heck is going on - is the spawned process sitting around waiting for OS permission to run?  Are the stream readers waiting?  Did the OS unload the DOS program that had been in memory when I was running the app yesterday, and it just takes a while to load it again?

It's not a tremendously consistent and reproducible thing, but seems to be generally related to overall computer load and the length of time since the app was last run.

Anyway, I was hoping if I could identify the thread the process was running in (this is a Windows32 machine, BTW), maybe I could tell something, or maybe I could tweak the priority of that thread.  If not, is there any sort of monitoring app I can attach to tomcat or to netbeans that might be of any use?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, an external tool like [**Process Monitor**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) would be your best option, in order to check what kind of resources that process keep.
One of those (like a file handle) could explain the timeout.

Comment: Will do, once I figure out how to find the process ID or something to identify the process.  I also need to figure out how to get Process Monitor to save a snapshot of a process that runs and exits within a matter of seconds.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the way to go. I was thiking of Process Explorer, which is not that helpful, but with Process Monitor, I can capture the events while I'm running my test, and then review them afterwards. And it turns out to be pretty easy to identify the process in the Process Tree view even without the handle, because of the path to the file that is being run.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, I was hoping if I could identify the thread the process was running in (this is a Windows32 machine, BTW), maybe I could tell something, or maybe I could tweak the priority of that thread.

There is no way to do this in pure Java, but you might be able to get some traction by using reflection to poke around in the private fields of the actual `Process` subclass.  (In the case of `UNIXProcess`, the UNIX pid is stored in a private field ...)

If you wanted to get more than the pid (or Windows equivalent) in Java, or if you wanted to change process priority, you'd need to do it via JNI.  (I recall seeing a Java + native code library for doing this kind of stuff on UNIX.)

---

But to be honest, I think you'd be better off solving this a different way.  For instance, try using a longer timeout if this is the "first time for the day".

Comment: Thanks, I'll look around the Process code and see if I can find a private field to latch onto.  This is all just for diagnostic purposes at this point.  I'd obviously like to try to find a way to avoid the bad customer experience of either timing out or having to wait a long time for a result.

Comment: In my opinion, Windows bootup is a bad user experience and there's no real cure.

Comment: I know, I know - but I have to play the cards I'm dealt.  Anyway, I'm able to get the process handle now with reflection, so that's a help, although running ProcessMonitor drags down my system to a near standstill - and yet doesn't necessarily reproduce my problem.